# Questions about tables in cas-dc-template

Tags: tables

I want the label and title to be centering, but failed. Now it's like below.
[image]

Finally, I want this picture to be this one.
[image]

this is my code. I would be very appreciated if you could help me.

```
\begin{table}[pos=h]
\caption{\centering Number of object in DroneVehicle dataset.}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\Xhline{1px}
\multirow{2}{*}{Categories} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{train} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{test} \\ \cline{2-5} 
                            & RGB         & Infrared    & RGB        & Infrared    \\ \hline
Car                         & 246,700     & 270,350     & 143,079    & 157,736     \\
Truck                       & 13,685      & 15,833      & 8,438      & 10,127      \\
Bus                         & 10,421      & 11,334      & 4,912      & 5,256       \\
Van                         & 7,275       & 7,701       & 4,660      & 5,007       \\
Freight car                 & 8,712       & 11,193      & 4,688      & 5,980       \\ \Xhline{1px}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: As always on the site, please provide a full but minimal example such that we don't have to guess your setup. Then it is a lot easier to help.